# transparent shape with arrow in upper corner

Tags: html, css, css-shapes, curve

Please see the image below.

[image: Desired result]

I want to add an arrow to the top right of a `div` which I am treating as editable input box.
Please help me how I can achieve this using CSS.
I **cannot use a SVG** since I need this as a `div` to show emoticons as images over it.

```
<div placeholder="Your message" id="Message">
...
</div>
```

Comment: Is your background a solid color or transparent?

Comment: yes man that would be helpful

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it like in the below snippet. The method used to achieve the shape is as given below:

- The main `div` element only has a top, bottom and left border. The right border is nullified because the element and its arrows needs to be transparent. With a transparent arrow, if a right border is present that would also get displayed.
- The arrow on the right is achieved using a `skew`ed element placed with respect to the right edge of the shape.
- The right border of the shape is achieved by using another pseudo-element whose size is the same as the height of the whole container - height of the arrow pseudo-element. This element is positioned with respect to the bottom right of the shape.

You can adjust the height and border-radius as required. I have set the positioning such that even a change in height/width of parent would not affect it.

```css
div.shape {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-right: none; /* not required as the shape needs to be transparent */
  border-radius: 8px; /* not required as the right border is done through pseudo element */
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}
div.shape:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: -2px; /* equal to border top of parent - no need to change*/
  right: -6px; /* for positioning - no need to change*/
  height: 15%; /* should be changed depending on height of arrow */
  width: 10%; /* should be changed depending on width of arrow */
  border-top: 2px solid gray;
  border-right: 3px solid gray; /* thicker border because skew makes it thin */

  /* to achieve the arrow like shape */ 
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom right;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-45deg);
  transform: skew(-45deg);
}
div.shape:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  right: -6px; /* for positioning - no need to change*/
  height: 85%; /* height of parent - height of arrow */
  width: 2%; /* no need to change */
  bottom: -2px; /* equal to border bottom of parent - no need to change*/
  border-right: 2px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px; /* for producing curve on bottom right */
}

/* Just for demo */

body {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, crimson, indianred, purple);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, crimson, indianred, purple);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, crimson, indianred, purple);
}
```

```html
<div class="shape">
  Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet...
</div>
```

---

The arrow can be added to the left side by changing the positioning attributes and the skew direction (from positive angle to negative angle) like in the below snippet.

```css
div.shape {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-left: none; /* not required as the shape needs to be transparent */
  border-radius: 8px; /* not required as the right border is done through pseudo element */
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
}
div.shape:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: -2px; /* equal to border top of parent - no need to change*/
  left: -6px; /* for positioning - no need to change*/
  height: 15%; /* should be changed depending on height of arrow */
  width: 10%; /* should be changed depending on width of arrow */
  border-top: 2px solid gray;
  border-left: 3px solid gray; /* thicker border because skew makes it thin */

  /* to achieve the arrow like shape */ 
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom right;
  -webkit-transform: skew(45deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(45deg);
  transform: skew(45deg);
}
div.shape:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: -6px; /* for positioning - no need to change*/
  height: 85%; /* height of parent - height of arrow */
  width: 2%; /* no need to change */
  bottom: -2px; /* equal to border bottom of parent - no need to change*/
  border-left: 2px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px; /* for producing curve on bottom right */
}

/* Just for demo */

body {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, crimson, indianred, purple);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, crimson, indianred, purple);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, crimson, indianred, purple);
}
```

```html
<div class="shape">
  Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet...
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

### Filter: drop-shadow()

The compatibility is **[limited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Browser_compatibility)**

Yet the effect is pretty cool :P

```css
.inputcontainer {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px black);
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 1px black);
}
.input {
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  width: 280px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0;
  right: -5px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  transform: skew(-45deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputcontainer">
  <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Your message"/>
  <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

### Box-shadow:

Here the compatibility is **[a lot better](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow#Browser_compatibility)**

```css
.inputcontainer {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px black);
}
.input {
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  width: 280px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px gray;
}
.input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0;
  right: -8px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  transform: skew(-45deg);
  box-shadow: 2px -2px 0px 0px gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputcontainer">
  <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Your message"/>
  <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```