# Give border to custom shape made by css containing an input type

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I have this custom shape made with css. I need to give a border to it but I have unsuccessful so far. How can I give it a border?

```css
.comment-input-container {
  width: 96%;
  float: left;
}
input[type='text'] {
  border: 0px !important;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 5px;
}
.arrow-left {
  float: left;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #fff;
  border-right: 10px solid #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 300px;">
  <div class="arrow-left">

  </div>
  <div class="comment-input-container">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Reply to comment..." />
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, another problem is that the arrow and input break for smaller devices, that is, the input gets stacked underneath the arrow. Is there a better way of creating this shape that is also responsive and stays intact?

Comment: Your arrow is already created using border. So, you can use the methods mentioned here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057669/border-within-border-css/18058163#18058163 to add a border around it. **Edit:** On the other hand you can create the whole thing us the approach mentioned here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011363/transparent-shape-with-arrow-in-upper-corner/30011454#30011454.

Comment: thanks for the link, Is there any other way of creating the shape that is also responsive? In the example I have give the parent container a fixed width, however in reality, the parent container is responsive and for small screens, the shape breaks. Should I use min-width to counter this?

Comment: If you use the border method then making it responsive is tough because borders don't support percentages. You'd have to use viewport units to make them responsive. Alternately, have a look at the second link that I posted. That should give a responsive output.

Comment: Thanks, will have a look.

Comment: You're welcome. Also, if you have any specific queries regarding that linked answer you can find me in [this chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69317/css-shapes-svg-and-designs).

Comment: Sure, I am struggling to take the arrow from the right to the left, but I'll try more. Will ping you if I am unable to do so! Thanks again!

Comment: I have added a snippet with the arrow on the left also to the old answer (refer to the last snippet there). I am not adding it as answer here because it would look like am rep hunting.

Comment: Definitely, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Harry, I was able to work out a laregely responsive solution:

```css
.comment-input-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border-left: none;
  /* not required as the shape needs to be transparent */
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
}
.comment-input-container:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0px;
  left: -7px;
  height: 26%;
  width: 10%;
  background-color: #f6f7fb;
  border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  border-left: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom right;
  -webkit-transform: skew(45deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(45deg);
  transform: skew(45deg);
}
.comment-input-container:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: -7px;
  height: 74%;
  width: 5%;
  max-width: 15px;
  bottom: 0px;
  border-left: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  background-color: #f6f7fb;
}
input[type="text"] {
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  border-left: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: #f6f7fb;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) !important;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  outline: none;
}
input[type="text"]:focus {
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  border-left: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: #f6f7fb !important;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) !important;
  padding: 10px;
  outline: none;
}
.comment-box {
  margin-left: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="comment-box">
  <div class="comment-input-container">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Reply to comment..." />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the special shape is the last one? It's 0px x 0px, but you should see something since you gave it a 10px border. Unfortunately, The border is white so it blended in with the white background. I made the shape 1px x 1px and the background black so you can see the shape better.

```css
body { background: black; }
.comment-input-container {
  width: 96%;
  float: left;
}
input[type='text'] {
  border: 0px !important;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 5px;
}
.arrow-left {
  float: left;
  width: 1px;
  height: 0px;
  border-bottom: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
  border-right: 10px solid #f2f2f2;
  box-shadow: inset 4px 2px 22px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.57);
  outline: 2px inset rgba(0, 0, 0, .35;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 300px;">
  <div class="arrow-left">

  </div>
  <div class="comment-input-container">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Reply to comment..." />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is white space beneath the arrow. I dont want that.

Comment: On the left top corner of the shape? I ran your code snippet and it is showing a little white space beneath the arrow.

Comment: Letme make the background lighter, then maybe I can see it better...

Comment: How about now you might have to refresh. Oh, I get it it's a speech bubble like in the comics.

Comment: I dont see the border though? I need the border thats the whole point.

Comment: That shape is a square a border cannot run through a block diagonally, If you use a dark background for contrast it defines the shape quite nicely. If you want a triangle try SVG or an icon ◄

Comment: see Harry's link in the comment thread on my question. It works fine.