# How to make responsive bubble with triangle on left site

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-shapes

I try to make a bubble which will be responsive no matter on user device and also it have a triangle on left site.

How it should looks like:
[image]

What I tried:

HTML:

```css
.responsive-bubble {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 80%;
  min-width: 80%;
  min-height: 1.5em;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ebebeb;
  border: #ebebeb solid 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  float: right;
}
.responsive-bubble:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: calc(89% - 3px);
  left: calc(-4% - 3px);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 18px 18px 0;
  border-color: #7F7F7F transparent;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive-bubble">“And here comes some really long text which doesnt mean anything however it have to be long to provide a lot of characters and see how this buble works when long text is here and even when nearly no text is here and so on. I hope you know what I mean
  So i am adding few additional words! So i am adding few additional words! So i am adding few additional words!”</div>
<div class="responsive-bubble">“Some shorter text come here to see how it looks when it's not so many text HERE! Some shorter text come here to see how it looks when it's not so many text HERE!”</div>
<div class="responsive-bubble">“Some shorter text come here to see how it looks when it's not so many text HERE!”</div>
```

What doesn't work:
It looks like bubble it self is responsive correctly, but I have problem with triangle on left site, it's no on right position depend on bubble.

DEMO:
For demo I changed border and so on just to provide more details:
https://jsfiddle.net/jkdurdjr/2/

Is here anyone who can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You may want to have a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011363/transparent-shape-with-arrow-in-upper-corner/30011454#30011454

Comment: I'm confused, just like this -> **https://jsfiddle.net/jkdurdjr/8/**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question that I linked in comments is a bit too complex for your case and it needs to be adapted a lot to fit your case. There is a much simpler solution for your case and so I'm adding it separately.

There is simply no need to use `calc` functions for positioning the arrow here. All that is needed is for the arrow to be positioned with respect to the `top` and the `left` based on its dimensions and that of its parent. Set `top` as `-4px` where `-4px` is needed to move the element up by no. of pixels equal to the `border-top` of its parent. Generally when children are added, it gets positioned below the `border` of the parent and so we need to offset for it. Similarly the offset needs to be done for the left border of the parent also + the entire arrow needs to be visible and so we offset it to the left by `-22px` which is nothing but the `(size of the arrow (it's border width) + the left border of parent) * -1`.

```css
.responsive-bubble {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 80%;
  min-width: 80%;
  min-height: 1.5em;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ebebeb;
  border: #ebebeb solid 4px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-color: #ebebeb;
  border-style: solid;
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.responsive-bubble:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;  /* just set it w.r.t to top, where the value is negative of border-top */
  left: -22px;  /* this needs to be inverse of border-width of this element + border-left of parent */
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 18px 18px 0;
  border-color: #ebebeb transparent;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive-bubble">“And here comes some really long text which doesnt mean anything however it have to be long to provide a lot of characters and see how this buble works when long text is here and even when nearly no text is here and so on. I hope you know what I mean
  So i am adding few additional words! So i am adding few additional words! So i am adding few additional words!”</div>
<div class="responsive-bubble">“Some shorter text come here to see how it looks when it's not so many text HERE! Some shorter text come here to see how it looks when it's not so many text HERE!”</div>
<div class="responsive-bubble">“Some shorter text come here to see how it looks when it's not so many text HERE!”</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I changed your CSS style and it looks as you expected:
https://jsfiddle.net/940vaade/

The main difference is in, `bottom` and `left` properties. They are based on your triangle dimensions (`border-width` property).

Notice I‘ve changed widths and heights (they are in `em` units, not `px`). Also, in your CSS, border radius for `.responsive-bubble` had different values (20px with prefixes, 0px without prefix).

Comment: Nice answer there. One alternate to the offsets specified in my answer is to have no borders on the parent at all (like in your answer).

Answer (score 1):

You are very close, I changed the `border-width` and replaced `bottom` with `top`

```
.responsive-bubble:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top:0;                // relative to top, not to the bottom
    left: calc(-4% - 3px);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 25px 0 0 25px;  // second 0 referrs to the right side, 3rd to the top
    border-color: #7F7F7F transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jkdurdjr/9/

Comment: Hey @Alexandru , thank you for your answer. I thumb up it. But to be fair I mark Harrys answer as correct ( he was first ) however THANKS AGAIN